# Pivot the table

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

```
Id Year Values
1 2014 10
1 2015 4
1 2016 7
1 2017 17
2 2014 5
2 2015 6
2 2016 7
2 2017 9
```

Answer should be

```
Id 2014 2015 2016 2017
----------------------
1    10    4    7   17
2     5    6    7    9
```

I tried as below

```
Select * 
from crosstab(select id,value,year from table)
As res(id int,year int,year int,year int,year int,year int);
```

Comment: i assume the id of the last record `1 5 6 7 9`  in the expected results should be 2 right?

Comment: Yes the result should be 2

Comment: The question seams to be a simple typographical error.. The SQL code in the `crosstab()` function atleast needs to be single quoted like so `crosstab('select id,value,year from table')`.. The manual defines it as [crosstab(text sql)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html).. I've posted a possible other method which can also be used to pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Another option than using `crosstab()` would be using `GROUP BY` and some aggregate function like `MAX()` with `CASE END` to pivot. 
 
As extra bonus this is ANSI SQL so it will run in most RDBMS systems.

```
SELECT 
   Id
 , MAX(CASE WHEN <table>.Year = 2014 WHEN <table>.Values ELSE 0 END) AS 2014
 , MAX(CASE WHEN <table>.Year = 2015 WHEN <table>.Values ELSE 0 END) AS 2015 
 ...
 ...
FROM 
 <table>
GROUP BY 
 <table>.Id
```