# I need to pivot the table and get the count for every year present for the respected ids

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I need to retrieve the data in year wise that is count(values) for year and it should be in format like year and count(values)

```
select * 
from crosstab(select id, year, count(values) from table)
as res(id int, year1 int, year2 int, year3 int, year4 int)
```

Data in Table

```
============================
Id | Year        | values
============================
1  | 2015-01-10  | 2
1  | 2015-02-11  | 3
1  | 2016-03-11  | 5
1  | 2017-05-07  | 3
1  | 2014-01-01  | 1
2  | 2014-01-10  | 7
2  | 2015-03-03  | 9
2  | 2016-08-08  | 8
2  | 2017-09-09  | 5
```

Actual Result

```
===============================
id | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017
===============================
1  | 1    | 5    | 5    |3
2  | 7    | 9    | 8    |5
```

Comment: it would be good to format this a bit better and add some more detail as to what is the issue

Comment: This is exactly the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536015